# Passing props to child component is giving me RangeError in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js.

I am trying to send the props to child component which is a response from api call. But when ever I try to add the props in the child component it is giving me RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Here is the screenshot of error

[image]

**Here is the code:**

**page.jsx**

```
import styles from './page.module.css';
import EmployeeDashboardNavbar from './serverComponents/EmployeeNavbar';
import EmployeeDashboardContent from './serverComponents/employeeDashboardContent';

const EmployeeDashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles["emp-dashboard-top"]}>
      <div className={styles["emp-dashboard-body"]}>
        <EmployeeDashboardNavbar />
        <EmployeeDashboardContent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EmployeeDashboard;
```

**EmployeeDashboardContent.jsx**

```
import { findTaskswithDeptAdmin } from "@/actions/taskActions";
import EmpCards from "../clientComponents/employeeCard";
import styles from "./server.module.css";
import EmployeeCalendar from "../clientComponents/calendar";

const EmployeeDashboardContent = async () => {
  const tasksOfUser = await findTaskswithDeptAdmin({
    empId: "652a39fbfd78c72ec09f26b5",
  });
  const filteredTasks = tasksOfUser.filter((tk) => tk.completionStatus === "Assigned")
  console.log(filteredTasks);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles["emp-dash-main"]}>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex" }}>
          <div className={styles["emp-dash-main-left"]}>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div className={styles["emp-header-nav"]}>
                  <div className={styles["emp-header"]}>
                    <h3>Krish</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <EmpCards />
              </div>
              <div className={styles["emp-body"]}>
                <div className={styles["emp-meeting-schedule"]}>
                  <button className={styles["emp-dashboard-add-employee"]}>
                    Meeting Details
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <table className={styles["emp-dash"]}>
                    <thead>
                      <tr className={styles["emp-table-head"]}>
                        <th>Task</th>
                        <th>Head</th>
                        <th>Department</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {tasksOfUser
                        .filter((tk) => tk.completionStatus === "Assigned")
                        .map((task) => (
                          <tr
                            className={styles["emp-dashboard-table-data"]}
                            key={task._id}
                          >
                            <td>{task.taskName}</td>
                            <td>{task.deptId.name}</td>
                            <td>{task.adminId.adminName}</td>
                            <td>{task.deadline}</td>
                          </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <EmployeeCalendar tasks={filteredTasks}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles["emp-dash-main-right"]}>hiii</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default EmployeeDashboardContent;
```

**EmployeeCalendar.jsx**

```
"use client";

import Calendar from "react-calendar";
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';

import styles from "./client.module.css";

const EmployeeCalendar = ({tasks}) => {
  console.log(tasks)
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={`${styles["emp-calender"]} ${styles["react-calender"]}`}
        style={{ display: "grid", placeItems: "center" }}
      >
        {/* <div>
          <h4 style={{ cursor: "pointer", color: "red" }}>Today</h4>
        </div> */}
        <Calendar />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default EmployeeCalendar;
```

Here is the data of filteredTasks

```
[
  {
    taskName: 'task 3',
    adminId: {
      adminName: 'Krish',
      email: 'krish@gmail.com',
      password: '123',
      document: 'PAN',
      __v: 0
    },
    deptId: { name: 'HR', __v: 0 },
    deadline: '2023-10-21',
    status: false,
    completedDate: '',
    completionStatus: 'Assigned',
    createdAt: '2023-10-23T12:27:33.523Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-10-23T12:27:33.523Z',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

I have tried to send response statically, and magically it worked. But, I don't why it is not working in dynamically rendered data.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it out, but it looks like your `filteredTasks` inside EmployeeDashboardContent is recalculated frequently. Can you try to memoize the filteredTasks value?

Comment: EmployeeDashboardContent is the server component.
The memo hook cannot be used in the server component.

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake in my code. The data which I was receiving from findTaskswithDeptAdmin function was not converted into the JSON, that's why I was getting the error.

The main issue was that the data which was coming from mongoose was not in the form of string and to pass the data from one component to another component through props the data has to be the type of string.

For reference I will attach the code of findTaskswithDeptAdmin function (I will share both the code, previous code of function when I was getting error and the code of function after the error was solved.

**findTaskswithDeptAdmin() (when error was stemming)**

```
export const findTaskswithDeptAdmin = async (query) => {
  try {
    const result = await Task.find(query);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

**findTaskswithDeptAdmin() (when the error was solved)**

```
export const findTaskswithDeptAdmin = async (query) => {
  try {
    const getTasks = async () => {
      const result = await Task.find(query);
      return result;
    };
    const actualData = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await getTasks()));
    return actualData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```